# Unable to find topMenu - Magento

Tags: magento

Not sure what is going on here:

in my page.xml i have the following code:

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
    <label>Navigation Bar</label>
    <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml" />
</block>
```

When I try to update page/html/topmenu.phtml with a few minor HTML changes they are not rendered?

When I remove this code the category menu disappears indicating it is the controlling xml.

When I update page/html/header.phtml in the same theme template it renders the changes.

I have also deleted this template file entirely and also any other template file that maybe a fall back like default../../topmenu.phtml - but the menu renders fine indicating that it is not using these template files?

I have also tried updating top.phtml in the same manner with no luck?

Cache has been cleared on every update.

I must be missing something - any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

My first guess would be that `catalog.topnav` has another module changing its template to something other than `page/html/topmenu.phtml` or your system has a class rewrite for `page/html_topmenu` that points to a class which doesn't use templates to render the navigation.

If you're running a debugging tool like Commerce Bug check the template set for the top menu block.

[image]

As well as the class set for `page/html_topmenu`

[image]

Lacking a debugging tool, add some temporary debugging code to `app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Topmenu.php` to test the template being set

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Topmenu.php
protected function _toHtml()
{
    var_dump($this->getTemplate());
    var_dump($this->getTemplateFile());
    return parent::_toHtml();
}
```

This will tell you which template your top navigation is using.  If nothing is output, then it's very likely your system has a rewrite for this class.

Comment: [Commerce Bug](http://commercebugdemo.pulsestorm.net/) sure looks like an interesting tool.

Comment: @benmarks I wouldn't work without it. `var_dump` based development can only bring you so far.

Comment: Hi Alan - thank you for the tip. Indeed it was a module that was causing the problem Frontend link manager was the culprit! You debugger looks really good, I've added it to my wish list if this project i'm working is in any way successful :)